# What is Smooth Streaming Media Element TotalBytesDownloaded

Tags: silverlight, streaming, media, smoothing

I want to know what is [TotalBytesDownloaded](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.web.media.smoothstreaming.smoothstreamingmediaelement.totalbytesdownloaded%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) field, in Microsoft.Web.Media.SmoothStreaming. MSDN conveniently states it as "The number of bytes downloaded.". But is it the number of video-bytes downloaded by the player or all the bytes including any other server requests and response you might be making on top of the player(for logging purposes)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's the total number of bytes downloaded for both video and audio requests for an AV presentation.